# Interpretation of Bayesian Probability Question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

As a summary, the question sets up a scenario were a company is testing the presence of dairy in foods. It uses two tests $A$ and $B$, which are both taken to be independent of one another.

The question seems as though it will require some variant of Bayes' theorem to answer.

---

I'm having trouble interpreting this line of the larger question,

> "However, when a product is dairy-free, the probability of **test A** indicating the presence of dairy given that **test B** will detect dairy is $0.2$."

If we define events as follows,

$A$ denotes *"test $A$ is positive"*

$B$ denotes *"test B is positive"*

$D$ denote *"dairy is present"*

What I can take from that particular passage is;

1. Dairy is not present in the particular food product,
2. $A$ tests positive when there is no dairy present,
3. $B$ tests positive when there is no dairy present and,
4. We're interested in $A$ testing positive given $B$ tested positive.

How would you set up this passage using probability statements and conditionals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This passage means that $$\mathbb P(A\mid B\cap \overline D)=0{.}2.$$
Other words we can express it as
$$
\mathbb P(A\mid B\cap \overline D)=\dfrac{\mathbb P(A\cap B\cap \overline D)}{\mathbb P(B\cap \overline D)}=\dfrac{\mathbb P(A\cap B\cap \overline D)}{\mathbb P(\overline D)\mathbb P(B \mid \overline D)}=\dfrac{\mathbb P(A\cap B\mid \overline D)}{\mathbb P(B \mid \overline D)}=0{.}2.
$$